# Using BB promise to create server with free port

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

When I run the create server & listen in my unit test some times I'm getting the following error:

EADDRINUSE,

Now I want to handle it by using module portscanner to find free port

I do it like this

```
var http = require('http');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var portscanner = require('portscanner');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/fail') {
        res.end("Failed");
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    }
});

Promise.promisifyAll(server);

server.listenAsync(portscanner.findAPortNotInUse)

module.exports = server;
```

This was working but not sure if it's stable code

my question is if it's OK to use it like this? and this is not some dirty workaround and if yes how can I handle it better?

Comment: Disregarding whether this is possible, it's a huge pain to manage services that do this. When JMX picks a random port, it's worthless for any network debugging (since that port is almost always closed). You're much better off trying a single port and dying if it's already in use.

Comment: @ssube - Thanks but this is just for running unit test...

Comment: Typically, [small (unit) tests shouldn't be using the network](https://testing.googleblog.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html) at all. They should run in a controlled environment where you know the ports are good (or you can pass in an alternate port in the config/cli).

Answer (score 0):

You could promisify portscanners findAPortNotInUse() and call server.listen in the promises then()-function

```
Promise.promisifyAll(portscanner);

portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(3000, 4000, '127.0.0.1').then(function(port){
    server.listen(port);
}).catch(function(){
    // your error handling
})
```

Now, portscanner searches for a free port between 3000 and 4000 on localhost and after a free port is found, server listens to that port

Comment: Thanks I've tried it and its not working...Im not able also to put BP to see why (in the server.listen(port) line ) ...will try again

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portscanner) portscanner requires some arguments. I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using promise in this case, you can simply use something like :

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 5000, '127.0.0.1', (error, port) =>{
    server.listen(port);
});
```